# 'python3.10 -m tkinter' doesn't work on CentOS 7

Tags: python, centos, centos7, python-3.10

First, I installed openssl 1.1.1k package using the following source on CentOS 7. (https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1k.tar.gz)

Second, I installed tcl/tk packages using the following sources. (https://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/tcl/tcl8.6.12-src.tar.gz https://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/tcl/tk8.6.12-src.tar.gz)

Finally, I installed python 3.10.6 using the following source. (https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.6/Python-3.10.6.tar.xz)

However, I can't use tkinter module.
What should I do to use tkinter module.

The follow commands are what I do for tcl and tk.

```
su
cd /usr/local/src;
wget https://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/tcl/tcl8.6.12-src.tar.gz;
wget https://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/tcl/tk8.6.12-src.tar.gz;
tar -xvf tcl8.6.12-src.tar.gz;
cd /usr/local/src/tcl8.6.12/unix;
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/tcl;
make;
make test;
make install;
cd /usr/local/src;
tar -xvf tk8.6.12-src.tar.gz;
cd /usr/local/src/tk8.6.12/unix;
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/tk;
make;
make test;
make install;
ln -s /usr/local/tcl/lib/libtcl8.6.so /usr/lib64/libtcl8.6.so;
ln -s /usr/local/tk/lib/libtk8.6.so /usr/lib64/libtk8.6.so;
ln -s /usr/local/tcl/bin/tclsh8.6 /bin/tclsh8.6;
cd /usr/local/src;
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.6/Python-3.10.6.tar.xz;
tar -xvf Python-3.10.6.tar.xz;
cd /usr/local/src/Python-3.10.6;
./configure --enable-optimizations;
make altinstall;
```

```
pip3.10 install --upgrade pip
```

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (22.2.1)
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-22.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.0/2.0 MB 6.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-22.2.2
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 177, in emit
    self.console.print(renderable, overflow="ignore", crop=False, style=style)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/console.py", line 1673, in print
    extend(render(renderable, render_options))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/console.py", line 1305, in render
    for render_output in iter_render:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 134, in __rich_console__
    for line in lines:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/segment.py", line 249, in split_lines
    for segment in segments:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/console.py", line 1283, in render
    renderable = rich_cast(renderable)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/rich/protocol.py", line 36, in rich_cast
    renderable = cast_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/self_outdated_check.py", line 130, in __rich__
    pip_cmd = get_best_invocation_for_this_pip()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/entrypoints.py", line 58, in get_best_invocation_for_this_pip
    if found_executable and os.path.samefile(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/genericpath.py", line 101, in samefile
    s2 = os.stat(f2)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/pip'
Call stack:
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3.10", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 70, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 101, in main
    return self._main(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 223, in _main
    self.handle_pip_version_check(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 190, in handle_pip_version_check
    pip_self_version_check(session, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/self_outdated_check.py", line 236, in pip_self_version_check
    logger.warning("[present-rich] %s", upgrade_prompt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1489, in warning
    self._log(WARNING, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1624, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1634, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1696, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 968, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 179, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
Message: '[present-rich] %s'
Arguments: (UpgradePrompt(old='22.2.1', new='22.2.2'),)
```

```
pip3.10 install tk-tools
```

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting tk-tools
  Downloading tk_tools-0.16.0-py3-none-any.whl (173 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 173.4/173.4 kB 3.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting engineering-notation>=0.5
  Downloading engineering_notation-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.7 kB)
Installing collected packages: engineering-notation, tk-tools
Successfully installed engineering-notation-0.6.0 tk-tools-0.16.0
```

```
python3.10 -m tkinter
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 187, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 146, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 110, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

Comment: this should be import tkinter. No underscore.

Comment: @toyotaSupra _tkinter is the module that tkinter module import internally.

Comment: Presumably this is a start, try to reconfigure your python `import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why download from sources? `sudo yum install -y tkinter tk-devel` . Also see https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter

Comment: @BrodyCritchlow: `_tkinter` should only be imported by the tkinter module itself; it's not designed to be imported by an application.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Of course I tried `yum install tkiner tk-devel` (tk, tcl version 8.5), but it only works for python 3.6.8(latest version on CentOs 7 that is supported by yum). It didn't work in python 3.10.x. (python 3.10.x uses tk and tcl of version 8.6)